# Как написать код для загрузки видео с ютуба не используя ffmpeg?

Tags: python, youtube

я пытался написать код который загружет видео с ютуба по url но у меня вот такая ошибка

```
ERROR: You have requested merging of multiple formats but ffmpeg is not installed. Aborting due to --abort-on-error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(download('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHgt8giw1LY', 'Привет!'))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 9, in download
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(link, download=True)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1549, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, self.get_info_extractor(key), download, extra_info, process)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1560, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1709, in __extract_info
    return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1768, in process_ie_result
    ie_result = self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 2897, in process_video_result
    self.process_info(new_info)
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 3321, in process_info
    self.report_error(f'{msg}. Aborting due to --abort-on-error')
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1042, in report_error
    self.trouble(f'{self._format_err("ERROR:", self.Styles.ERROR)} {message}', *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ytiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 981, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
yt_dlp.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: You have requested merging of multiple formats but ffmpeg is not installed. Aborting due to --abort-on-error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

я понел что дело в ffmpeg но можно ли не прибегать к его использованию?

вот код который я использовал

```
import yt_dlp

def download(link, name='%(title)s'):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo+bestaudio/best', #берем самое лучшее качество видео и фото
        'outtmpl': '{}.%(ext)s'.format(name), #наше выбраное имя, если его не было, то стандартное - название видео на самом сайте
    }
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info_dict = ydl.extract_info(link, download=True)
        downloaded_file_path = ydl.prepare_filename(info_dict)
    print(f"Видео {downloaded_file_path} успешно загружено!")
    return downloaded_file_path


print(download('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHgt8giw1LY', 'Привет!'))
```

Comment: убери строчку ``'format': 'bestvideo+bestaudio/best',`` оно и так по умолчанию загружает самое лучшее качество

Comment: By default, yt-dlp tries to download the best available quality if you don't pass any options. This is generally equivalent to using -f bestvideo*+bestaudio/best. However, if multiple audiostreams is enabled (--audio-multistreams), the default format changes to -f bestvideo+bestaudio/best. Similarly, if ffmpeg is unavailable, or if you use yt-dlp to stream to stdout (-o -), the default becomes -f best/bestvideo+bestaudio.

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg нужен для склейки 'bestvideo+bestaudio' . попробуй без указания опций.

Answer (score -1):

в мане библиотеки yt_dlp
написано совершенно четко:

While all the other dependencies are optional, ffmpeg and ffprobe are highly recommended